# Width: auto only adjusting to half the side of div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, width

Could anyone please explain why on this page (and some of the other pages a part from Home and About) http://leedsragfashionshow.co.uk/wp/index.php/committee/, the title of the page is cut off showing only half of the word.

Sometimes on refresh it will show the title in full with the grey background and sometimes revert back to only showing half.

Experiencing this on Chrome

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to load fine on Firefox and Chrome. The only "title" I see being cut is the title html tag being cut because of tab size restriction in chrome. Maybe I'm misunderstanding? All looks fine.

Comment: I am referring to the actual title of the page within a div with a grey background, not the <title> tag

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a lot of width: 100% and width: auto. You might be overwriting yourself in a few places. Try removing some of those and see if that helps.

Comment: I ended up just setting a fixed width to all the page titles!